# Installing webistrano on ubuntu 13.10

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, webistrano

I'm trying to install [webistrano](https://github.com/peritor/webistrano) with latest ruby packages on ubuntu 13.10.
After inital configuration, each time when I'm trying to "bundle" things I'm getting following error:

```
confiq@home:~$ RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migraterake aborted!
    Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    bundler (~> 1.0.10) ruby

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (1.4.0.pre.1)
```

Of course, I tried to install older bundler

```
confiq@home:~/$ gem list bundler
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
bundler (1.4.0.pre.1, 1.3.5, 1.0.10)
```

But dosen't matter which version of bundler I'm installing it always fails on same error message.

I'm in middle of dependency hell and this is just small portion of it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is happening because the [project specification](https://github.com/peritor/webistrano/blob/master/Gemfile#L3) requires bundler `~> 1.0.10`. This means every version of bundler `1.0.x` is allowed, but not bundler `1.3` or `1.4`.

Even if you install an older version of bundler, by default the most recent one is used when you call `bundle` from the command line.

To force the use of an older version, you need to pass it in the following way

```
$ bundler _1.0.10_ ...
```

One additional node. Webistrano is a very old and unmaintained project. The last commit is older than 3 years ago.

I discourage you to use the project. It's likely you will encounter several other incompatibilities and the time you will waste trying to find a solution may not be worth.

Comment: I agree about time wasting :) Just, we got stuck with webistrano...
I found some project that allows to install webistrano on ubuntu 
https://github.com/jverdeyen/webistrano
I'll leave it here in case somebody need it...